# Are there Fortran compiler options for warning about write-after-write conflicts?

Tags: fortran, compiler-warnings

Let's say you have the following code:

```
INTEGER :: num_samples
num_samples = 10000
num_samples = 1
```

Obviously, the first `num_samples = 10000` does nothing, and its existence probably indicates a programmer error (e.g., the programmer meant to comment out the following line, or vice-versa). Are there any Fortran compilers that will warn for such write-after-write errors, and if so what options turn on the warning?
(I'm also interested if there are C++ compilers with such warnings, and if there are Java IDEs that provide such warnings, but right now I'm focusing on the Fortran side of things.)

Comment: I don't think there will be any compilers checking for that, or giving you an option to be warned about that.  There are some code analysis tools available you could try out, like 'forcheck', 'fortranlint', 'understand', that work for fortran source code.

Comment: I can't think of any.  There are compilers or tools to detect uninitialized variables and dead code (e.g., SPAG, http://www.polyhedron.com/spag0html).

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of strange question from my point of view. This write-after-write situation you mentioned is a **logical error**. Compilers detect mostly **syntax errors**. In some cases logical error may reveal themselves as syntax errors but not always.

A logical error means that you made a mistake in implementing your algorithm. You can notice it only upon testing. Or you can also try static program analysis (as steabert mentioned).

> I'm also interested if there are C++ compilers with such warnings, and if there are Java IDEs that provide such warnings, but right now I'm focusing on the Fortran side of things.

Take a look at functional programming languages. Due to immutability write-after-write situation just can't happen. ;-)

Comment: I disagree. Compilers can detect more than just syntax errors. Take unused dummy arguments, for instance. Not an error, but many (most?) compilers can give you a warning about those. I think compilers can detect the write-after-write situation easily (things like this are used in optimization, where the first assignment would just be skipped), but there's probably not enough demand for providing a warning to users.

Comment: @eriktous: yep. Maybe I putted it just too hard. You are right compilers can detect something more than syntax errors. My point was about that they should not do that necessarily.

Comment: A "true" functional programming language wouldn't allow write-after-write errors, but the implementations I'm familiar with of LISP are not 100% functional, and thus do suffer from this possibility. I think I remember hearing it as an idiom that all functional programming languages that support a GUI subvert a part of their functional nature in order to do so. (Although I realize that whenever one says "all" one will hear about the exception.)

Comment: LISP is not functional programming language, it is multi-paradigm.